# Filewriter issues - Java Android

Tags: java, android, file, filewriter

My filewriter does not seem to create a file.
 This is my code:

```
public void peopledetails_write(ArrayList<PeopleDetails> peopledetails_file) {
        ////numbers is the arraylist of numbers.
        ///names is the arraylist of names of people.
        ///Written to file like 01235 678 908, Daniel; 01245 645 123, Bob Marley; etc.
        ///Like a CSV file. 
        try{
            FileWriter writer_file = new FileWriter("PeopleDetailsFile");

            String filestring = ""; ///initializes filestring, which is written to the file.
            for(PeopleDetails person : peopledetails_file){
                String person_detail_string = "";
                person_detail_string = person.name + "," + person.number;
                filestring = filestring + person_detail_string + ";";

            }
            writer_file.write(filestring);
            writer_file.close();
        }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());

        }finally{
            ///Hopefully won't get an error here.
            Intent switch_menu = new Intent(this, MenuList.class);
            startActivity(switch_menu);
        }
    }
```

It acts on the finally, and takes the user back to the main menu of my app. I have managed to debug the section where this code is, and reckon that this is faulty code, as I get a `FileNotFound exception`, after this section should have written a file.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: if your issue got solved please accept the ans and upvote it.

Comment: where do you want to create a file? Internal Storage or ExternalStorage?

Comment: @Sush.  That is not good behaviour.  By all means remind the user to accept the correct answer but asking for upvotes is not good kharma.  The community does that for answers which are especially useful, innovative, insightful etc.  Your single line of code, with no explanations, probably deserves downvotes.

Comment: not even sure if my issue has been solved... but thank you anyway. Online in other places it says not to enter a full file path???

Comment: The most likely problem is that all of the sub directories in the path MUST exist before you create the file.  `FileWriter` will not do this.  We need more detail, such as where are you saving the file?  What is the value you pass to the method in peopledetails_file etc.

Comment: Can you explain @Simon I'm new to java... thanks

Comment: Imagine you are saving to the SDCard (we do not know, since you have not told us, nor what value is in peopledetails_file).  If the path is /sdcard/myapp/myfiles/ then the myapp and myfiles directories must exist.  FileWriter will not create them for you.  As I say, please provide more information or we are just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

here where your going wrong, unless api points to some specific directory, you should always
 use absolute file path(complete file path).

```
FileWriter writer_file = new FileWriter(complete_file_path);
```